# Porque sucede esto con los botones?

Tags: css3

Por qué sucede que al cliquear el checkbox, se le ve un cuadro a su alrededor?

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    float: left !important;
    margin-right: 6px !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    background: #333!important;
    border: 1px solid #333!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: #1565C0!important;
    border-color: #1565C0!important;
    background-image: url('http://snova.us/data/img/checked.png')!important;
    background-size: 10px!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
    background-position: center!important;
}
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" style="border: 0px;" onchange="setNames(!$(this).is(':checked'));"> Sin nombres</label>
```

Comment: Es la propiedad `outline` que pone el navegador cuando un elemento de formulario tiene el foco (es por accesibilidad, no se suele recomendar eliminarlo). Tampoco ocurre en todos los navegadores (supongo que estás probando en Chrome). Si quieres quitarlo la solución te la da @aldanux en su respuesta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo arreglas agregando la propiedad [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/outline)

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    outline: 0; /* <<< */
    float: left !important;
    margin-right: 6px !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    background: #333!important;
    border: 1px solid #333!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked {        
    background-color: #1565C0!important;
    border-color: #1565C0!important;
    background-image: url('http://snova.us/data/img/checked.png')!important;
    background-size: 10px!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
    background-position: center!important;
}
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" style="border: 0px;" onchange="setNames(!$(this).is(':checked'));"> Sin nombres</label>
```